# Docker Compose & Postgres Connection Refused

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, ffmpeg

I know this question has been asked a million times, and I've read as many of the answers as I can find. They all seem to come to one conclusion (db hostname is the container service name).

I got it to work in my actual code base, but it started failing when I added `ffmpeg` install to the Dockerfile. Nothing else had to be done, just installing FFPMEG via `apt-get install -y ffmpeg` would cause my python code to get the connection refused message. If I removed the ffmpeg install line, then my code would connect to the db just fine. Although re-running the container would trigger the dreaded connection refused error.

So I created a quick sample app so I could post here and try to get some thoughts on what's going on. But now this sample code won't connect to the db no matter what I do.

So here goes - And thanks in advance for any help:

`myapp.py`

```
# import ffmpeg
import psycopg2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting app...")
    # probe = ffmpeg.probe("131698249.mp4")
    # print(probe)

    try:
        connection = psycopg2.connect(
            user="docker", password="docker", host="db", port="5432", database="docker")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from test_table"

        cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
        print("Selecting rows from table using cursor.fetchall")
        records = cursor.fetchall()

        print("Print each row and it's columns values")
        for row in records:
            print(row)

        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
```

`Dockerfile`

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "myapp.py"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: docker
    ports:
      - "8000:5432"
    expose:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - pg_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  pg_data:
```

If I build and run the code: `docker compose up --detach`
Everything gets built and started. The Database starts up and gets populated with table/data from the `init.sql` (not included here)
The app container starts and the code executes, but immediately fails with the `Connection refused` error.

However, if from my computer I run: `psql -U docker -h localhost -p 8000 -d docker`
it connects without any error and I can query the database as expected.

But the app in the container won't connect and if I run the container with `docker run -it myapp /bin/bash` and then from inside the container run: `psql -U docker -h db -p 5432 -d docker` I get the Connection refused error.

If anyone has any thoughts or ideas I would be so grateful. I've been wrestling with this for three days now.

Comment: have you tried `localhost` within the python script?

Comment: From everything I've read the hostname used internally in the docker network is the service name. This would be `db` in this case. Out of desperation I tried it, but as I expected it didn't work.

Comment: If you wait a minute or so and run `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work?  (If the error is "connection refused", you have the right host name, and either you have the wrong port or the actual process in the container isn't running.  The port 5432 is the standard PostgreSQL port, so it's probably not that; but it is common for a database to take 30-60 seconds to initialize and possible for the application to start up first.)

Comment: I did think about that, which is why I added the `depends_on: db` statement. I just tried again, started the whole stack: `docker compose up -d`, then waited until my code timed out. Waited a couple minutes and then ran it again: `docker compose up -d`. Still got the `Connection refused` error (and did confirm I can still `psql` to the db from my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've resolved it. I was sure I'd tried this before, but regardless adding a `networks` section to the `docker-compose.yml` seemed to fix the issue.

I also had to do the second `docker-compose up -d` as suggested by David Maze's comment. But the combination of the two seem to have fixed my issue.

Here's my updated `docker-compose.yml` for complete clarity:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres-db:
    container_name: pg_container
    image: postgres:14.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: docker
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker
      POSTGRES_DB: docker
    ports:
      - "5500:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    networks:
      - dock-db-test

  myapp:
    container_name: myapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: "no"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - dock-db-test

networks:
  dock-db-test:
    external: false
    name: dock-db-test
```

Comment: Yep this was definitely the solution. I applied the change back to the original code base and everything is working beautifully. I added [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) to the `app` startup cmd so it waits for the `db on port 5432` to be live before running my app code.

Comment: I realized the reason I thought this didn't work when I tried it before. I had tried so many things I was not always following a clear path when I would try something. I kept making changes and the doing `docker run -it <image> /bin/bash` to get into the container and try to connect, but it would never be able to see the database even with the network info ... because I forgot `docker run` is not using the docker compose file. This time I ran `docker run -it -network dock-db-test <image> /bin/bash` and once in the container was able to access the db.